# Task to measure clock frequency in System Verilog (pass clock signal by reference)

Tags: task, system-verilog, verification

I'm new to SV for verification and as a first attempt to a object oriented testbench, I'm trying to verify a simple clock generator design.
I would like to constantly monitor the multple clock outputs of the macro, given a certain configuration and clock input. To do so I need to be able to measure the frequency of multiple clock signals.

Ideally, I thought of something like this for my `checker` class:

- get trigger and retrieve configuration details
- start a `freq_meter` task for each output clock I need to measure

Each `freq_meter` task would do the following:

- **receive a clk signal from the virtual interface**
- start time measure
- count N clock posedges
- return the evaluated frequency

```
class checker_monitor;
  virtual clkgen_if clkgen_vif;

  task run();
    // launch freq measure
    fork
      freq_meter(clkgen_vif.clk_out_1);
      freq_meter(clkgen_vif.clk_out_2);
      freq_meter(clkgen_vif.clk_out_3);
    join
    // check that returned frequencies are correct
  endtask

  task freq_meter(input logic clk, output logic freq);
    time_start = $time;
    repeat(N+1) @ (posedge clk);
    time_end = $time;

    period = (time_end - time_start)/N;
    freq = 1/period;
  endtask : freq_meter
```

Any suggestions on such a problem? I'm stuck now at passing a clock signal by reference to the task from the virtual interface.

Best,

abet

Answer (score 0):

Change the input parameter of the task to the reference parameter like in following snippet.

```
task freq_meter(ref logic clk, output int freq);
```

---

Note: As was pointed out in the comments this will work only when  `clkgen_vif.clk_out_N` are variables not nets. My assumption is that they are defined as `logic` in the `clkgen_if` interface.

---

EDIT: I've created a working example on EDAPlayground([link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/HSeL)). I also changed the output parameter to `int` instead of `logic` as frequency measurement would return only 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

change task freq_meter(ref logic clk, output real freq);
the output should be real since it's a frequency, it should solve your issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).